# Swift unable to retrieve child node firebase database

Tags: swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

My database looks like this

```
category
   subCat1
      item1
         someData: somedata
         storage: storageref
      item2
         someData: somedata
         storage: storageref
      item3
         someData: somedata
         storage: storageref
   subCat2
      item1
         someData: somedata
         storage: storageref
      item2
         someData: somedata
         storage: storageref
      item3
         someData: somedata
         storage: storageref
```

I would like to retrieve the value of the "storage" key in a specific subcategory node. I've tried tapping into one specific subcategory and retrieve to storage key with the following code:

```
let ref = Database.database().reference().child("category").child("subCat1")
    ref.observeSingleEvent(of: .value) { (snapshot) in

        for item in snapshot.children {
            let snap = item as! DataSnapshot
            let imageSnap = snap.childSnapshot(forPath: "storage")
            let dict = imageSnap.value as! [String: Any]
            let url = dict["storage"] as! String
            print(url)
        }
```

This code crashes the app on the line `let dict = imageSnap.value as! [String: Any]` with the error code `Could not cast value of type '__NSCFString' (0x10632a168) to 'NSDictionary' (0x10632b1a8)`

I've tried printing snapshot, snapshot.child, snapshot.value etc. None of these give me what I'm looking for, they either do not work, or give me one large dictionary containing subCat1, all items, someData and storage.

Update:

with the help of Sh_Khan's answer below, I'm able to print the storage strings for each item in the node, however my for in loop causes the all the strings to be printed 3 times each so I get a total of 3 x 3 urls when I only want 3 (one for each item)

Answer (score 1):

**Replace**

```
let dict = imageSnap.value as! [String: Any]
let url = dict["storage"] as! String
```

**with**

```
if let url = imageSnap.value as? String { }
```

Comment: When I do that the line bellow (let url = dict["storage"] as! String) gives the error "Cannot subscript a value of type 'String' with an index of type 'String'"

Comment: Great, that prints the value of my storage key for all items. However, the app also crashes on the let url line with the error code: "Could not cast value of type 'NSNull' (0x110cb1770) to 'NSString' (0x10fe210d0)."

Comment: Nice, it works now. However all the 3 storage strings one time for each item in my subCat node. So it prints a total of 3 x 3 lines of the same storage strings.

Answer (score 1):

Above Sh_Khan answer is correct, just try to unwrap item value using `if let` so you don't get crash. Your updated code below:

```
    let ref = Database.database().reference().child("category").child("subCat1")
        ref.observeSingleEvent(of: .value) { (snapshot) in

            for item in snapshot.children {
                if let snap = item as? DataSnapshot {

                 let imageSnap = snap.childSnapshot(forPath: "storage")
                 let url = imageSnap.value as? String

                 print(url)

                }
            }
   }
```

Comment: This works, however it prints all three urls as many times as the number of items in my subCat1 node. So since I have 3 items in this node it prints the urls 3 x 3 times. How can I make it print only once for each url?

Comment: All have unique storage url, and same key: "storage"